# API for getting information about regions (states) of a country

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app with a reference book and a quiz about regions of Russia. It have a list of regions, and clicking every item you can get detailed information about the region.

**List of regions**

[image: List of regions]

**Detailed information about Moscow region**

[image: Detailed information about Moscow region]

I'm interested in where to get the source information about the regions and in what form it is better to store it for loading into the application.

Currently I have a JSON-file with array of regions that I manually form.

```
{ 
    "regions":
    [
        {
            "name": "Белгородская область",
            "capital": "Белгород",
            "latitude": 50.7080119, 
            "longitude": 37.5837615,
            "flag": "flag_belgorod.png",
            "polygon": "belgorod_geojson",
            "autocode" : 31,
            "population" : 1549876,
            "area" : 27134,
            "district" : "Центральный",
            "founded" : "6 января 1954 года",
            "description" : "Белгоро́дская о́бласть (неофиц. Белого́рье, Святое Белого́рье, Белгоро́дчина, Белгоро́дщина) — субъект Российской Федерации, расположен в юго-западной части России в 500—700 км к югу от Москвы, на границе с Украиной..."
        },
        {
            "name": "Брянская область",
            "capital": "Брянск",
            "latitude": 52.8873315, 
            "longitude": 33.415853,
            "flag": "flag_bryansk.png",
            "polygon": "bryansk_geojson",
            "autocode" : 32,
            "population" : 1210982,
            "area" : 34857,
            "district" : "Центральный",
            "founded" : "5 июля 1944 года",
            "description" : "Бря́нская о́бласть — субъект Российской Федерации, расположенный в Центральной России к юго-западу от Москвы, на границе с Украиной и Белоруссией. ..."
        },
        {
            "name": "Владимирская область",
            "capital": "Владимир",
            "latitude": 56.0503336, 
            "longitude": 40.6561633,
            "flag": "flag_vladimir.png",
            "polygon": "vladimir_geojson",
            "autocode" : 33,
            "population" : 1378337,
            "area" : 29084,
            "district" : "Центральный",
            "founded" : "14 августа 1944 года",
            "description" : "Влади́мирская о́бласть — субъект Российской Федерации, входит в Центральный федеральный округ..."
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

- But maybe there is an API that will help me get the information in finished form?
- Is there any API for getting the list of all regions (states) of a country and the information about them, or I still have to collect this data myself?

Comment: This is not really a question for Android. You would be better of searching for free or paid platforms that supply this information.

Comment: You may want to have a look at maxmind.com